# Is there a way to mirror a label xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Counter.Page1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="60" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Label Text="{Binding MainPageEditorText}" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Scale"
                        Value="1" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Scale"
                        Value="0.99" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Is it possible to mirror the label completely not just reverse the text. I am building an app that needs to be able to be projected from an iPad screen so I need it to be mirrored.

Comment: Hi , have you solved it ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time .

Comment: Try RotationZ= 180.

Answer (score 1):

I might not completely understand what you mean by mirroring; but if it's similar to an image mirroring, like looking at yourself in the mirror; then a rotate or flip is what you need. This code will guide you..

```
   <StackLayout Margin="20">
                <Label Text="No Rotation"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/ten8ba4rcfqm.png"/>
                <Label Text="RotationX 180"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/ten8ba4rcfqm.png" RotationX="180"/>
                <Label Text="RotationY 180"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/ten8ba4rcfqm.png" RotationY="180"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]